# MS Azure SQL: how do I import CSVs and set up push notifications?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, azure-sql-database

Recently had a client who needed me to connect his online store databases to a POS system using MS Sql Azure 2014.

However, the normal methods using BULK insert nor SQl Service broker do not work. I usually receive errors like "Not available in this version of SQL server.

I tried the online azure website but I'm on windows 10 which does not seem to work well with silverlight....and using visual studio to access the database, does not accept bulk insert commands either....

Any guides on how to use to utilize these... wityh azure...normal SQL server 2014 ways do not work.

Comment: SSIS can connect to Azure SQL.  You will have to run the SSIS package from a different server though.  Not sure on licensing ramifications.  If it's a simple CSV then you could use Powershell to loop through the CSV and insert the data.  What are the performance requirements?

Comment: I just want the ability....nothing fancy....I'll try the powershell route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the BCP utility to import and Export.
as the following states, Azure doesn't seem to support the Bulk insert... 
[see here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-transact-sql-information/)